# not showing data in table view swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

i have one table view with two labels. I need to display the data which are coming from json. But now its not showing any data in table view:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate
{
    let yourJsonFormat: String = "JSONFile" // set text JSONFile : json data from file
                                            // set text JSONUrl : json data from web url

    var arrDict :NSMutableArray=[]

    @IBOutlet weak var tvJSON: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if yourJsonFormat == "JSONFile" {
            jsonParsingFromFile()
        } else {
            jsonParsingFromURL()
        }
    }

    func jsonParsingFromURL () {
        let url = NSURL(string: "url")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in

        }
    }

    func jsonParsingFromFile()
    {
        let path: NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("days", ofType: "json")!
        let data : NSData = try! NSData(contentsOfFile: path as String, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMapped)


    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return arrDict.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell : TableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! TableViewCell
        let strTitle : NSString=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("name") as! NSString
        let strDescription : NSString=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("rating") as! NSString
        cell.lblTitle.text=strTitle as String
        cell.lbDetails.text=strDescription as String
        return cell as TableViewCell
    }
}
```

Any thing i missed,please help me out.

I am not able to see any data in my table view...

Comment: where arrDict get it's values?

Comment: i learnt from this tutorial http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/json-parsing-example-swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is partially correct, I followed your question

**Step-1**

> Right click on the info.plist file, select open as, Source code. Add the lines of code that allow the http connection to this server.

[image]

do like

**Step-2**

**For Server request**

**sendAsynchronousRequest** is deprecated in this place use

```
 func jsonParsingFromURL () {
    let url = NSURL(string: "url")
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
  print("done, error: \(error)")
  let dict: NSDictionary!=(try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary 
  arrDict.addObject((dict.valueForKey("xxxx") 
  tvJSON .reloadData()

}
dataTask.resume()


}
```

**For local Request**

```
func jsonParsingFromFile()
  {
    let path: NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("days", ofType: "json")!
    let data : NSData = try! NSData(contentsOfFile: path as String, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMapped)
       let dict: NSDictionary!=(try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary 
  arrDict.addObject((dict.valueForKey("xxxx") 
  tvJSON .reloadData()

}
```

**Update and Edit**

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var showtable: UITableView!
 var arrDict :NSMutableArray=[]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

     self.jsonParsingFromURL()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func jsonParsingFromURL () {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://kirisoft.limitscale.com/GetVendor.php?category_id=1")
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        print("done, error: \(error)")
        if error == nil
        {
        self.arrDict=(try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSMutableArray

        print(self.arrDict)

            if (self.arrDict.count>0)
            {

                self.showtable.reloadData()
            }

       // arrDict.addObject((dict.valueForKey("xxxx")
        }


    }
    dataTask.resume()


}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return arrDict.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let CellIdentifier: String = "cell"

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)
    }


    cell?.textLabel!.text=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("name")   as? String
     cell?.detailTextLabel!.text=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("rating")   as? String

    return cell!
}

}
```

you can get the output like

[image]

For [**sample Project**](https://www.sendspace.com/file/jzc0lh)

Comment: ok, can you please modify this code to print the json data in this api link. So that i can understand the flow of it !!

Comment: @user5513630 -- sure bro.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthick  yes its worked well. but when i run my table view , for first time its not showing any thing, i need to pull down lable view( like refresh), then only its showing data ? why??? i get error `This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.
`

Comment: i have searched in so, `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    // code here
})`   this code where i have to insert to rectify my problem

Comment: give the some time to load bro, why you do like the full option , no need

Comment: and also i have one label  which will show number of title data in my tabel view. but now its showing zero.   `
        Resultcount.text = "\(arrDict.count) Results"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106795/discussion-between-anbu-karthik-and-user5513630).